# Shadowing variable within a for loop statement

Tags: pine-script

I'm currently writing a strategy using Pine-script, which is also my first experience writing codes. Then I encountered this problem regarding for loops.

```
        if bcktst and strategy.opentrades < 6
        for n = 0 to 5
            n = strategy.opentrades
            strategy.entry("Short #" + str.tostring(n + 1),strategy.short, when=barstate.isconfirmed, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
            if sld > emaLTFs
                strategy.exit("Close #" + str.tostring(n + 1),"Short #" + str.tostring(n + 1), limit=tp1, stop=sld + atr,
                 trail_price=tst1, trail_offset=(tst1 * beper1)/syminfo.mintick)
            else
                strategy.exit("Close #" + str.tostring(n + 1),"Short #" + str.tostring(n + 1), limit=tp2, stop=emaLTFs + atr,
                 trail_price=tst2, trail_offset=(tst2 * beper2)/syminfo.mintick)
```

The code displays my expected output as shown in the image below(Chart Display).

[Chart Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YxJv.png)

However it shows a prompt about shadowing variable and I'm concerned since I will repeat the code for several times for different triggers and it will flood the console with the same prompt.

> line 239: Shadowing variable 'n' which exists in parent scope. Did you want to use the ':=' operator instead of '=' ?

I tried replacing the operator ( = to := ) but the script cannot be executed and the console displays (see image - Error prompt)

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 239: Variable 'n' cannot be mutable.

[Error prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRZY0.png)

I have tried several methods but this is the only for loop statement that displays what I intended.

So my question is, are there any workarounds to remove the prompt or am I missing something.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the pine-script version?

Comment: Pine-script //@version=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-assigning a value to the counter variable (`n` in this case) of the for statement.

```
for n = 0 to 5
    n = strategy.opentrades
```

Use another variable name and you will be fine.

```
for n = 0 to 5
    n_trades = strategy.opentrades
```

Comment: Thanks man! Changing the variable did remove the prompt but the entry orders stacks up, adding an if statement after the for loop did it.